# AttributeError raised on "from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D" statement

Tags: python, matplotlib, windows-10

I was doing a homework assignment in a Jupyter notebook (which resolves the assignment fine.) I also ran the same code on my home dev machine for familiarity (albeit with some adaption), which happens to raise the error below. Usually there's no issue doing so... until now.

My home machine:

- matplotlib 3.1.0 per PIP list (not an inclusive list, there're other packages)
- Python 3.7.3
- Atom 1.40.1 x64 with Script package 3.18.1
- Win 10 Home build 17763

I narrowed the error source to (everything else commented-out):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

which, when un-commented raises the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.axis' has no attribute
'_make_getset_interval'
```

I understand that mpl_toolkits is supposed to be included with matplotlib yet I cannot access the Axes3D() function.

I've read through (many) previous postings regarding issues with matplotlib; trying their solutions...none have worked yet. I tried swapping my imports one-before-the-other below per post suggestion... with no solution. I also tried uninstalling version 3.1.0, and using 3.1.1, but ran into other conflict issues with confusion matrix assignments so I stayed with 3.1.0 until (3.1.2?) is available.

How can I fix this? Ideas? Thanks in advance all!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # tried this commented-out too

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # this line by itself throws the error message


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\scripts_scikit-learn.py", line 1040, in <module>
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .axes3d import Axes3D
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 34, in <module>
from . import axis3d
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axis3d.py", line 457, in <module>
class XAxis(Axis):
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axis3d.py", line 458, in XAxis
get_view_interval, set_view_interval = maxis._make_getset_interval(
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.axis' has no attribute '_make_getset_interval'
[Finished in 1.26s]
```

Comment: The only explanation for this error I can think of is version 3.1.1 not being completely uninstalled (or only partially installed).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take another look at my /local, /roaming folders, perhaps a fragment of the 3.1.1 package is present and (interfering?) with my 3.1.0 version. I'll look. Thanks again.

Comment: No 3.1.1 elements found but, while I was inside the axes3d and axis3d files referred in the Traceback I learned that:

  - The axes3d.py file contains an Axes3D function definition

  - The axis3d.py file contains sub-classes XAxis(Axis), YAxis(Axis), and ZAxis(Axis) which do contain the _make_getset_interval() methods. 

I don't know what this means as far as 'matplotlib.axis' just yet...

Comment: That's the point. Matplotlib 3.1.0 should not contain `_make_getset_interval`, but since you have it, it would mean you actually do have some files from 3.1.1.

Comment: Oh I see. When I commented that I didn't find 3.1.1. elements I was looking at the /matplotlib and matplotlib-3.1.0.dist-info folder names. I didn't know that 3.1.0 wasn't supposed to have the _make_getset_interval attribute in the first place.
  Thank you very much for taking some time on this!